# url.action and @html.PageLinks lines causing my System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am an aspiring junior developer who is currently following the PRO ASP.NET MVC 5 book by Adam Freeman. I am thoroughly enjoying following the examples and learning as I create my own version of the template application. However, I have lately encountered a very annoying problem of which I tried my best to encourage myself to not ask it on StackOverflow as it may have been asked.

I am currently on Chapter 7 of this book, creating a sports store. The main part I  am stuck in is finding out why I get a System.OutOfMemoryException whenever I use the @Html.PageLinks inside my Divs. Whenever I comment those Pagelinks lines out, the application works like a charm. I tried to follow all the solutions given by Microsoft and other similar forum questions such as [this html helper link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103586/custom-html-helper-not-working),  [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798115/html-helper-class-method-not-working) and the official Microsoft page (support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820108). I went over my code over and over to check if it was the same as the one in the book. I'm sorry if this particular question has already been answered but I just couldn't find something to help me.

The List.cshtml

```
@model TheKicks.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@using TheKicks.WebUI.HtmlHelpers;
@using TheKicks.WebUI.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}
@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}

<div class= "btn-group pull-right">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List",
    new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
</div>

<div class="pager">
    <div>
        @Html.PageLinks(Model.P‌​agingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x }))
    </div>

</div>
```

The PagingHelpers.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TheKicks.WebUI.Models;

namespace TheKicks.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                                    PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                                    Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; 1 <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if(i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                    tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
                }
                tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
           }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If I have missed anything  I must apologize for the inconvenience as I may have not looked in the right places. I have a big problem asking for help and this is my first time.

Thank you

Comment: Typo in your loop `for (int i = 1; 1 <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)` cause infinite loop. modify to `for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)`

Comment: @MikeDebela I guess you got the problem. But should it be `for (int i=1; i < pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)` ?

Comment: @SivaGopal The condition the OP used is *`1 <= ...`* . Should be *`i <= ...`*

Comment: Thank you so much guys I feel so blind right now haha, @SivaGopal I believe the book had the conditional section like that too, not sure why though but maybe it has something to do with making sure to make as many buttons as possible? Thanks again guys!

Comment: @AbdulAl-haj Technical books often contain errors. Often, the publisher posts errata and corrections on their site. I don't see your error mentioned in the [errata for this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-5.productCd-1118794753,descCd-ERRATA.html) however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 <= pagingInfo.TotalPages` is always true, so your loop will run indefinitely until you run out of memory. Replace 1 with i variable.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was racking my brain as to what I did wrong. The good thing is a learnt about other things as I tried to fix it!